# Collection of Classes - Array property not populating correctly

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, collections

I am migrating a vb6 program to vb.net. essentially the below function is creating a collection of classes.  I use the key as the test_id for accessing the individual classes within the collection elsewhere.  the only issue that I am having is that the property Sieves for the class is being updated with each successive class addition to the collection. in other words - when I execute on the first loop/first class - I assign the sngSieveArray to my class's property (.sieves).  all is good and data is exactly what db contains.  upon the second loop - as soon as the sngsievarray is populated with the current class's data - the 1st class's sieve array is updated to this same data.

in all - there are 3 classes - so each .sieves property is assigned the last class's sieve array.

I'm at a total loss as to how this went wrong - all other properties in the class are retained with each successive class being created.

```
Public Function GetSieveTestsInLot(mix_app_id As Long, mix_lot_id As Long, Optional,combinedMixLot As Long = 0, Optional combinedMixLot2 As Long = 0, Optional boolExclude As boolean = False) As Collection
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim rsTests As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim mycmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim mySieveTest As clsSieveTest
    Dim sngSieveArray(0 To 12) As Single

    Dim theConn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.AsphaltConnectionString)
    If Not (theConn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
        theConn.Open()
    End If

    strsql = "select mix_lot.MIX_LOT_ID,LOT_NUMBER, EXCLUDED,SAMPLE_TEST_ID, mix_lot.MIX_APPLICATION_ID, p.* from " _
        & "(select TEST_PERCENT_PASSING.PER_PASSING, TEST_PERCENT_PASSING.SIEVE_ID, TEST_PERCENT_PASSING.TEST_ID from TEST_PERCENT_PASSING) as t " _
        & "pivot (min(per_passing) for Sieve_id in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13])) p inner join TEST_DATA_CALC on TEST_DATA_CALC.TEST_ID = p.TEST_ID " _
        & "inner join MIX_LOT on MIX_LOT.MIX_LOT_ID = TEST_DATA_CALC.MIX_LOT_ID where MIX_APPLICATION_ID = " & mix_app_id & " And (MIX_LOT.mix_lot_id = " & mix_lot_id & " or mix_lot.mix_lot_id = " & combinedMixLot _
    & " or mix_lot.mix_lot_id = " & combinedMixLot2 & ")"

   

    mycmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    mycmd.CommandText = strsql
    mycmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    mycmd.Connection = theConn

    rsTests = mycmd.ExecuteReader

    GetSieveTestsInLot = New Collection
    If rsTests.HasRows Then
        Do While rsTests.Read
            If Not (boolExclude = True And rsTests!excluded = True) Then
                mySieveTest = New clsSieveTest
                With mySieveTest
                    .test_id = rsTests!test_id
                    .mix_lot_id = rsTests!mix_lot_id
                    .lot_number = rsTests!lot_number
                    .mix_app_id = mix_app_id
                    .sample_test_id = rsTests!sample_test_id
                    .test_exlcuded = rsTests!excluded

                    For i = 0 To 12
                        For j = 0 To rsTests.FieldCount - 1
                            '   MsgBox(rsTests.GetName(j).ToString)
                            If rsTests.GetName(j).ToString = (i + 1).ToString Then
                                '    MsgBox(rsTests.Item(j).ToString)
                                sngSieveArray(i) = rsTests.Item(j)
                            End If
                        Next j
                    Next i

                    .sieves = sngSieveArray
                End With

                GetSieveTestsInLot.Add(mySieveTest, CStr(mySieveTest.test_id))
            End If

        Loop
        rsTests.Close()
    End If

    rsTests = Nothing
    mycmd = Nothing
    theConn.Close()
    theConn = Nothing
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox("An error has occured in GetSieveTestsInLot in clsSieveTest with Error number: " & Err.Number & " defined as" & vbCrLf _
    & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Program Failure")
    rsTests = Nothing
    mycmd = Nothing
    theConn.Close()
    theConn = Nothing
End Function
```

MIX_LOT_ID  LOT_NUMBER  EXCLUDED SAMPLE_TEST_ID MIX_APPLICATION_ID TEST_ID     1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8             9             10            11            12            13

---

141         1           0        1              36                 430         5.15          100           100           100           90.7          76.3          49.6          35.3          24.8          17.7          13.1          8.5           5.5
141         1           0        2              36                 431         5.35          100           100           100           91.2          78.5          48.6          35.4          25            18.6          13.4          8             4.9
141         1           0        3              36                 432         5.16          100           100           98.8          84.8          74.1          53.8          38.4          26.8          19            13.7          9.1           5.2

(3 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because arrays are reference types.  The .sieves property of each instance of your clsSieveTest all reference the same instance of the array.  You need to move the declaration of sngSieveArray *inside* your Do While loop so that each new instance of your clsSieveTest gets its own array.

Comment: chris - thank you! just moved the dim statement into the do loop and as you stated - runs perfectly now.  just so that I can understand why... this code was identical in vb6 - why did the array not need to be created this way in that older vb version? just thinking the reason could be beneficial for other conversion snags...  regardless - thanks for the soln.